# Не могу написать рекурсивную функцию, которая определяет, являются ли все цифры числа нечетными или нет

Tags: javascript

```js
function funcEncoded(num) {
  let str = num.toString();
  console.log(str);
  if (str.length < 1) {
    return 'Yes';
  } else if (str[0] % 2 === 0) {
    return 'No';
  } else {
    str = str.substring(1);
    num = +str;
    return funcEncoded(num);
  }
}

console.log(funcEncoded(359));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(+"");
```

Исправляю код, удаляя все ненужное :).

```js
function funcEncoded(num) {
  let str = num.toString();
  console.log(str);
  if (str.length < 1) {
    return 'Yes';
  } else if (str[0] % 2 === 0) {
    return 'No';
  } else {
    str = str.substring(1);
    //num = +str;
    return funcEncoded(str);
  }
}

console.log(funcEncoded(359));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :) Но я не понял почему так..

Comment: @KarenZakharyan Посмотрите на первый фрагмент кода в ответе. Преобразование в число пустой строки дает ноль.